# How to make PanTool and ZoomTool behave if plot origin is 'top left'?

Tags: enthought, chaco

I'm trying to use PanTool and ZoomTool in a Chaco plot whose origin is set to 'top left' but the behavior of these tools is not as expected. Panning moves in the opposite direction and box zooming doesn't necessarily zoom to the highlighted region. Example code is:

```
plot.plot((x_key, y_key), origin='top left')
plot.tools.append(PanTool(plot))
plot.overlays.append(ZoomTool(plot, tool_mode='box', always_on=False))
```

If `origin='top left'` is removed, the panning and zooming behavior is as I'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really late reply, but basically the origin needs to be set on the main `Plot` instance, instead of the call to its `plot` method. (The `origin` set when initializing `Plot` gets passed into `plot` also)

```py
import numpy as np

from enable.api import Component, ComponentEditor
from traits.api import HasTraits, Instance
from traitsui.api import UItem, Group, View

from chaco.api import ArrayPlotData, Plot
from chaco.tools.api import PanTool, ZoomTool


class Demo(HasTraits):

    plot = Instance(Component)
    traits_view = View(
        Group(
            UItem('plot', editor=ComponentEditor(size=(900, 500))),
        ),
    )

    def _plot_default(self):
        x = np.linspace(-2.0, 10.0, 100)
        data = ArrayPlotData(x=x, y=np.sin(x))

        # This works
        plot = Plot(data, origin='top left')
        plot.plot(('x', 'y'))

        # This doesn't
        # plot = Plot(data)
        # plot.plot(('x', 'y'), origin='top left')

        plot.tools.append(PanTool(plot))
        zoom = ZoomTool(component=plot, tool_mode="box", always_on=False)
        plot.overlays.append(zoom)
        return plot


if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo = Demo()
    demo.configure_traits()
```